# No window menus in freenx

Tags: gnome, opensuse, menu

I recently upgraded an openSUSE 11.3 install to 11.4 by downloading the DVD, burning it, & chosing the upgrade option upon booting to it. I used all the upgrade defaults. Upon coming back up, I added the FreeNX zypper repository & installed the latest FreeNX. Connecting via FreeNX works, but I'm not able to see any window menus on any of my applications. They get stuck to the top left corner of the screen &/or they don't have the window border surrounding the window (as in the top bar that contains the minimize/maximize buttons).

I've verified it's not a user problem because I created a new user & logged in as the user for the first time & it still happened to that user too.

*** EDIT ***

Client is OS X 10.6.7 using NX Client by NoMachine, ver 3.4.0-8.  I should also point out I have other servers running FreeNX that still work fine, none of which are openSUSE 11.4 however.  I think it is an openSUSE 11.4 specific problem.

*** EDIT 2 ***

Desktop environment on openSUSE is Gnome (whatever the standard is for 11.4).  Window manager is the default, so I guess Nautilus.

I should point out that it works fine locally & with VNC, so it must be a FreeNX problem...

*** EDIT 3 ***

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: What are you connecting **to** with FreeNX? (OS, GUI environment, …)

Comment: see edits in original post.

Comment: @churnd: Ah, from your original question I thought the client was running on SuSE. What desktop environment or window manager are you running on SuSE then?

Comment: another edit...

Comment: An anonymous user mentioned in a [suggestion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/356) that this is limited to OS X clients

Comment: @michael, it is.  I tried on Windows & Linux & it works fine on both.  I have no idea why only OS X would be affected.

Comment: I have the same problem, but from Windows clients.  It affected just a handful of screens on openSuSE 12.2, but now that I've upgraded to 12.3 it affects more.  The good news is that those apps I can just run via Cygwin/X, but still, it's annoying to have windows/apps that just won't display via NoMachine.